# R Markdown XTable producing ## before the table output

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

When I produce a report with R markdown using xtable, the table output begins with several lines of '##' before showing the output table. I am not sure exactly what this means nor how to get rid of it.

````
```{r sector select info, tidy=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(xtable)
print(xtable(data), type = "html", include.rownames = T, floating=FALSE)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by adding comment=NA

````
```{r sector select info, tidy=FALSE, comment=NA, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(xtable)
print(xtable(data), type = "html", include.rownames = T, floating=FALSE)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The hashes are a result of R thinking it's printing a usual vector. You can check the output by calling `print(xtable(data), ...)` interactively.

xtable output is html.

Make sure chunk options are set to `results = 'asis'`, which tells the markdown compiler to directly use the html output of the chunk and include it into the final output.

````
```{r sector select info, results='asis', tidy=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(xtable)
print(xtable(data), type = "html", include.rownames = T, floating=FALSE)
```
````